# How to erase a chatroom I created myself

Tags: support, status-completed, chat

[my chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115211/ubuntu-20-04-1-upgrade-failure-error-dist-upgrade-failed-broken-packages-afte) It was never in use the question was solved before

I do not want to leave my trash behind

Comment: Do read this post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271270/846219

Comment: @technastic_tc does that say anything about deleting rooms?

Comment: Mod tools – room deletion
Rooms that are inactive for seven days will automatically be deleted, but you have the ability to delete chatrooms as needed via delete this room from the room↓ menu, or by going to the room’s info page, switching to the access tab, and clicking the delete button.
When should I delete a room? Since inactive chatrooms are automatically deleted, it’s not often necessary to delete a room. However, you may wish to delete a room it is no longer being used (private rooms for moderation purposes), or appears to exist only for nefarious purposes. Deleting a room prevents...

Comment: Yes, for mods. Does it also say regular users can delete rooms?

Comment: There's no mention of regular users deleting chat rooms. But anyway.. "*Since inactive chatrooms are automatically deleted, it’s not often necessary to delete a room.*"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't worry about it. Inactive rooms are deleted automatically by the system. I don't remember if non-mods can delete the rooms they created, but if you can, it will be on the "Access" tab.

So, try going to https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms, find your room, click on the "info" link of the room, go to "access" and see if you have a delete button. If you do, great. If not, never mind it will be deleted in a few days anyway.

Comment: I can delete it for you, if you like. I am a mod on another site, which means I am a mod on chat as well.

Comment: that would be nice @terdon

Comment: @nobody the room has been deleted.

Answer (score 4):

Related post on Meta SE: [How do you delete a room on chat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57099/280883)

Related chat FAQ:  [Will these rooms exist forever?](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#retention)

Quote (emphasis mine):

> Rooms will exist indefinitely, so long as there is at least one person actively talking in the room. A room is considered worth retaining if it has more than **15 messages by at least 2 users**.
>
> Rooms not worth retaining which are **inactive for 7 days will be deleted**. Rooms worth retaining which are inactive for 14 days will be frozen. Frozen rooms do not allow any new messages to be sent, and are not shown in the default room list to prevent cluttering the rooms interface.

TL;DR: Post nothing and it will be cleaned up automatically in a week.

*(terdon already deleted this one manually though, as mentioned in his own answer)*